# Disallow view of specific file on Apache

Tags: php, apache, file, .htaccess, file-permissions

In my site I've some file used by my application where are putted the log information.
For example a log file is "access.log", and i write in by PHP.
If a visitor go to www.mysite.ext/access.log , can see the file and all the information inside it.
How can I disallow this?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this in your `.htaccess`

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|pinc|ini|phps|fla|psd|log|sh)$">
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Will block `.log` and other common files you don't want people to access.

Comment: If I want to set this option for all the files with these specific extensions of entire site, it is the same? or the upper solution is valid only for the current folder's files?

Comment: If you put this in the .htaccess in your root folder then it will affect the entire site. Apache first runs the .htaccess in the folder of the requested file and then checks for an runs the .htaccesses in the parent folders.

Comment: Use `log(\.\d+(\.gz)?)?` if you are logrotating the log files and thus end up with access.log, access.log.1, access.log.2.gz etc

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this in Apache, you can add the following to your .htaccess:

```
<files access.log>
deny from all
</files>
```